# Parsing a JSON array using Json.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I'm working with Json.Net to parse an array. What I'm trying to do is to pull the name/value pairs out of the array and assign them to specific variables while parsing the JObject.

Here's what I've got in the array:

```
[
  {
    "General": "At this time we do not have any frequent support requests."
  },
  {
    "Support": "For support inquires, please see our support page."
  }
]
```

And here's what I've got in the C#:

```
WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(dest);
WebResponse objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);

    //Here's where I'm stumped

}
```

I'm fairly new to JSON and Json.Net, so it might be a basic solution for someone else.  I basically just need to assign the name/value pairs in a foreach loop so that I can output the data on the front-end.  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can get at the data values like this:

```
string json = @"
[ 
    { ""General"" : ""At this time we do not have any frequent support requests."" },
    { ""Support"" : ""For support inquires, please see our support page."" }
]";

JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);

foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
    {
        string name = p.Name;
        string value = (string)p.Value;
        Console.WriteLine(name + " -- " + value);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uox4Vt

Comment: You Rock... That did it for me

Comment: Sir, Could you tell me how can I get/read all data in response.I mean my value is ´closed´ and I have 80 value from my response as a list.How can access that values ? help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Use Manatee.Json
https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Json/wiki/Usage

And you can convert the entire object to a string, filename.json is expected to be located in documents folder.

```
        var text = File.ReadAllText("filename.json");
        var json = JsonValue.Parse(text);

        while (JsonValue.Null != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I've migrated my docs to GitHub Pages: https://gregsdennis.github.io/Manatee.Json/usage/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this is about Json.NET but times are a-changing so if anybody stumbles here while using .NET Core/5+ System.Text.Json please don't despair because
[Try the new System.Text.Json APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/) from .NET Blog show an example of this.

> ```
> [
>    {
>        "date": "2013-01-07T00:00:00Z",
>        "temp": 23,
>    },
>    {
>        "date": "2013-01-08T00:00:00Z",
>        "temp": 28,
>    },
>    {
>        "date": "2013-01-14T00:00:00Z",
>        "temp": 8,
>    },
> ]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(json, options))
> {
>    int sumOfAllTemperatures = 0;
>    int count = 0;
>
>    foreach (JsonElement element in document.RootElement.EnumerateArray())
>    {
>        DateTimeOffset date = element.GetProperty("date").GetDateTimeOffset();
>        (...)
> ```