# Json.Net Changing from JObject loops to JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm pulling a JSON feed that looks like this.

```
{
    "bank": [
        {
            "id": 35,
            "name": "bank 1",
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "epId": 407,
                    "epName": "FRED001"
                },
                {
                    "epId": 516,
                    "epName": "FRED002"
                },
                {
                    "epId": 625,
                    "epName": "FRED003"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "name": "bank 2",
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "epId": 426,
                    "epName": "HENRY001"
                },
                {
                    "epId": 553,
                    "epName": "HENRY002"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "bank 3",
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "epId": 1802,
                    "epName": "GEORGE001"
                },
                {
                    "epId": 920,
                    "epName": "GEORGE002"
                },
                {
                    "epId": 1052,
                    "epName": "GEORGE003"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The end goal is to search using the known epName 'FRED001', and to retrieve the corresponding epId '407, output to a MessageBox.

I can do this in C# by using loops e.g:

```
JObject jResults = JObject.Parse(jsonfeed);
JToken jResults_bank = jResults["bank"];

foreach (JObject bank in Results_bank)
{
    JToken jResults_bank_endpoint = bank["endpoints"];
    foreach (JObject endpoint in jResults_bank_endpoint)
    {
        if (bank["epName"].ToString() == "FRED001")
                {
            MessageBow.Show(bank["epId"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

However this doesn't seem like the best way to do it and I'm convinced that I should be doing this in C# by building an array. How can I achieve the same outcome with a `JArray`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing json array using json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726197/parsing-json-array-using-json-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to explicitly loop *or* change how you're parsing - you can just use LINQ with the JSON:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("Test.json");
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(text);
        var ids = from bank in json["bank"]
                  from endpoint in bank["endpoints"]
                  where (string) endpoint["epName"] == "FRED001"
                  select (string) endpoint["epId"];
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, excellent. It's easy when you know how. Thanks.
To extend this further, say I wanted to also retrieve "name": "bank 1", could I do this by editing the 'var ids'?

Comment: Think I might have figured it out:

`var ids = from bank in json["bank"]
from endpoint in bank["endpoints"]
where (string) endpoint["epName"] == "FRED001"

select new
{
 epId = (string)endpoint["epId"],
 bankName = (string)bank["name"],
};

foreach (var id in ids)
{
 Console.WriteLine(id.epId);
 Console.WriteLine(id.bankName);
}`

Comment: @PhilH: Sorry, didn't see the edit to your comment - but yes, that's basically it.

Comment: @JonSkeet performance-wise, lync query is better or using two for-loops?

Answer (score 1):

Or easy way would be to do just loop through it like this.

```
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(text);

        foreach (var id in json["bank"])
        {
           // your condition here
            if(id["epName"]=="FRED001")
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                JObject JObj = (JObject)yourjsontext;
                JArray JArr = (JArray)JObj["bank"];
                for (int i = 0; i < JArr.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(JArr[i]["id"].ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(JArr[i]["name"].ToString());

                    foreach (var endpoints in JArr[i]["endpoints"])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(endpoints["epId"].ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(endpoints["epName"].ToString());
                    }
                }
```