# How to parse the array of JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json

I need to parse the JSON data which is collection of array using C#.

```
ItemRelations: [
    {
        rel: "System.Links.H-Forward",
        source: {id: 123456,url: "https://somename.domain.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/Items/123456"},
        target: {id: 231856,url: "https://somename.domain.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/Items/231856"}
    }
]
```

I can parse simple JSON string but when it comes the scenario like above how should i proceed?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726197/parsing-a-json-array-using-json-net link.it might help u

Comment: Search for Newtonsoft.Json and read some docs. It's really powerful, and you probably dont even need to do much. Also visual studio has a function Edit->Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json. This might help

Comment: Instead of a simple object or array, the JSON you pasted is an array of objects. Hope that helps.

Comment: The posted text is not valid json, specifically the keys need to be embedded in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate class for your json using [Json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/#). Then using Json.Net from nuget:

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"{ItemRelations: [
    {
        rel: ""System.Links.H-Forward"",
        source: {id: 123456,url: ""https://somename.domain.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/Items/123456""},
        target: {id: 231856,url: ""https://somename.domain.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/Items/231856""}
    }
]}";

    var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

    //Linqpad
    //parsed.Dump();
}

public class Source
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Target
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class ItemRelation
{
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public Source source { get; set; }
    public Target target { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<ItemRelation> ItemRelations { get; set; }
}
```