# How to read each data from json array and assign it to SQL Server IN clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, json

Client application sends a json array to my .net application. I'm receiving it using name value collection. Now I want to read it's value and assign it to an `IN` clause of a SQL query.

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
NameValueCollection nvc = context.Request.Form;

string co_json = nvc["co_json"];
// jsArray : [{"roll_number":"11","mark":"68"},{"roll_number":"22","mark":"70"}]";

// I want to get the two roll numbers from above json and need to pass it to SQL 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from  student_details where roll_number IN ( ???) ", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15726500/289319

Comment: If you construct your IN clause by concatenating strings supplied by the user then be aware of opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the json to a custom c# object using [Newtonsoft JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)
You can create a class like this:

```
public class RollMark 
{
    public string roll_number {get;set;}
    public string mark {get;set;}
}
```

now you can do this:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
NameValueCollection nvc = context.Request.Form;
string co_json = nvc["co_json"];// jsArray : [{"roll_number":"11","mark":"68"},{"roll_number":"22","mark":"70"}]";

//collect all rollMarks in json to c# list
var rollMarks = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RollMark>>(co_json );
```

And you can now add parameters in your query like this:

```
//format your IN query
string[] paramArray = rollMarks.Select(x, i) => "@settings" + i).ToArray();
string query = string.Format("select * from  student_details where roll_number IN ({0})", string.Join(",", paramArray));
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < rollMarks.Count(); ++i)
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@settings", rollMarks[i].roll_number)
}
da.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, split your json array to find each item of array. next, create a class that has each proprties of your item. finally deserialize your each json item to the class.