# Jquery Post JsonString to c#. How do I parse it

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have a Json here and post it to the server.

```
    newJson.push({ Klasse_Id: parseInt(key), MaxTeilnehmer: value.MaxTeilnehmer });
$http.post('@Url.Content("~/Gw2RaidCalender/SaveEvent")', {
                    model: saveEventObject,
                    klassenModel: JSON.stringify(newJson)
                }).then(function successCallback(result) {
                    console.log(result.data);
                }),
                    function errorCallback(result) {
                        console.log(result.data);
                    };
```

Now in my C# code i have this

```
public string SaveEvent(EventModel model, string klassenModel)
    {
        JObject result = JObject.Parse(klassenModel);
```

Now i get this Error

```
Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray.
```

It looks like its not an valid Json string !?

```
"[{\"Klasse_Id\":1,\"MaxTeilnehmer\":2}]"
```

But I checked it on https://jsonlint.com/ and it says its valid.

I want to get the values out of this Json.

EDIT:

I solved it and now I can save the data

```
var jsonKlassen = JArray.Parse(klassenModel);
            foreach (JObject content in jsonKlassen.Children<JObject>())
            {
                int klasse_Id = (int)content.Property("Klasse_Id").Value;
                int maxTeilnehmer = (int)content.Property("MaxTeilnehmer").Value;
                var klassenmodel = new Klasse2EventModel
                {
                    Klasse_Id = klasse_Id,
                    MaxTeilnehmer = maxTeilnehmer,
                    Event_Id = newEventId
                };
                _db.Klasse2EventModel.Add(klassenmodel);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a JSON array using Json.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726197/parsing-a-json-array-using-json-net)

Answer (score 0):

Because this JSON string contains an array. Try this:

```
var result = JArray.Parse(klassenModel);
```