# Using JArray.Parse(json) on an associative array

Tags: c#, json.net

I've put together the following code [from this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15726500/1445985)

```
JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json);
foreach(JObject jsonObject in jsonArray.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach(JProperty jProperty in jsonObject.Properties())
    {
        int id = jProperty.id;
        string name = (string)jProperty.Name;
        textBox1.AppendText(id.ToString() + " // " + name + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

A sample of the JSON I'm trying to parse is as following:

```
[{"id":"219","name":"Jimmy"},{"id":"220","name":"Bobby"},{"id":"218","name":"Arthur"}]
```

The answer I referenced deals with parsing key => value pairs, how can I parse an associative array?

Comment: Its just an array of key value pairs.  Key: Id, Value `219` (or `"219"`).  You could deserialize to get at the data more easily especially since you appear to be consuming all of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON doesn't have "associative arrays". It has arrays and objects.

What you have here is an array of objects. So, `JArray.Parse` will give you a `JArray`, and each item in it is itself a `JObject`:

```
var array = JArray.Parse(json);
foreach(JObject obj in array)
{
    int id = obj.Value<int>("id");
    string name = obj.Value<string>("name");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'm still really new to C# so these kind of things I need to learn.  Really appreciate your response.