# Deserializing HTTP response

Tags: c#, json, http, deserialization

I am unable to deserialize my HTTP response. Could anybody tell me how exactly to do this?

I initially used List to deserialize the response, but it threw me a null exception since the response is a json array.

```
int count=0;
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<getAllDevices.Class1>>(receivedData);
Console.WriteLine("\n\nReceived Data________________\n" + receivedData + "\n");
 foreach (var item in obj)
     {
        if(item.name=="device")
        Console.WriteLine(item.name);
        foreach(var item2 in item)
           {
             if(item2.action_def.id=="increase")
                count++;
           }
      }
```

My getAllDevices class has the following:

```
class getAllDevices
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    //public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    public class Class1
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public Discovery discovery { get; set; }
        public bool is_authorized { get; set; }
        public bool is_available { get; set; }
        public bool is_enabled { get; set; }
        public bool is_visible { get; set; }
        public bool deleted { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string vendor_name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Hardware_Id[] hardware_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public Datastream[] datastreams { get; set; }
        public Trigger[] triggers { get; set; }
        public Condition[] conditions { get; set; }
        public Action[] actions { get; set; }
        public DateTime last_updated { get; set; }
        public DateTime authorization_updated_on { get; set; }
        public Credentials credentials { get; set; }
        public object[] preferences { get; set; }
        public string[] parent_ids { get; set; }
        public string classification { get; set; }
        public object[] states { get; set; }
        public string subtype { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    }
    public class Value
    {
        public bool visible { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string datastream_key { get; set; }
    }

    public class Action
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public object last_executed { get; set; }
        public Action_Def action_def { get; set; }
        public Param2[] _params { get; set; }
    }
    public class Discovery
    {
        public bool fake_discovery { get; set; }
    }

    public class Action_Def
    {
        public bool hidden { get; set; }
        public bool show_as_manual_action { get; set; }
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
        public bool requires_push_message { get; set; }
        public string simple_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Param2
    {
        public Ui2 ui { get; set; }
        public Value1[] values { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public object default_value { get; set; }
        public int limit_lower { get; set; }
        public int limit_upper { get; set; }
        public string values_datastream_key { get; set; }
        public string values_datastream_type_id { get; set; }
        public string substitution_type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ui2
    {
        public object presentation_value { get; set; }
        public string _interface { get; set; }
        public int step_size { get; set; }
        public int step_hold_size { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value1
    {
        public bool visible { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string datastream_key { get; set; }
        public string _id { get; set; }
    }
    public class Credentials
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
        public int expires_in { get; set; }
        public bool connected { get; set; }
        public long last_updated { get; set; }
    }

    public class Metadata
    {
        public string modelNumber { get; set; }
        public string thermostatRev { get; set; }
        public string runtimeRev { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string thermostat_id { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public int house_id { get; set; }
        public int dev_cat { get; set; }
        public int sub_cat { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hardware_Id
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public object id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datastream
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public Current_Value current_value { get; set; }
        public DateTime last_updated { get; set; }
        public Datastream_Def datastream_def { get; set; }
    }

    public class Current_Value
    {
        public object value { get; set; }
        public Away away { get; set; }
        public Home home { get; set; }
        public Sleep sleep { get; set; }
    }

    public class Away
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string climateRef { get; set; }
    }

    public class Home
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string climateRef { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sleep
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string climateRef { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datastream_Def
    {
        public bool log_update { get; set; }
        public bool log_duplicate_update { get; set; }
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Trigger
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public object last_triggered { get; set; }
        public string datastream_id { get; set; }
        public Trigger_Def trigger_def { get; set; }
        public Param[] _params { get; set; }
    }

    public class Trigger_Def
    {
        public bool repeatedly_trigger { get; set; }
        public bool hidden { get; set; }
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string datastream_id { get; set; }
        public string default_condition { get; set; }
        public string default_value { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
        public string simple_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Param
    {
        public object[] values { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string substitution_type { get; set; }
        public string default_condition { get; set; }
        public object default_value { get; set; }
        public string values_datastream_key { get; set; }
        public Ui ui { get; set; }
        public int limit_lower { get; set; }
        public int limit_upper { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ui
    {
        public string _interface { get; set; }
        public int step_size { get; set; }
        public int step_hold_size { get; set; }
    }

    public class Condition
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public object last_state_change { get; set; }
        public string datastream_id { get; set; }
        public Condition_Def condition_def { get; set; }
        public Param1[] _params { get; set; }
    }

    public class Condition_Def
    {
        public bool hidden { get; set; }
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string datastream_id { get; set; }
        public string default_condition { get; set; }
        public string default_value { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
        public string simple_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Param1
    {
        public Value[] values { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string substitution_type { get; set; }
        public string default_condition { get; set; }
        public object default_value { get; set; }
        public string values_datastream_key { get; set; }
        public Ui1 ui { get; set; }
        public int limit_lower { get; set; }
        public int limit_upper { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ui1
    {
        public string _interface { get; set; }
        public int step_size { get; set; }
        public int step_hold_size { get; set; }
    }
    }
}
```

When I use

```
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<getAllDevices.Rootobject>(receivedData);
    CrestronConsole.PrintLine("\n\nReceived Data________________\n" + receivedData + "\n");
    foreach (var item in obj.Property1)
    {
    }
```

I get:

```
 Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 
    'yonomi_one_test_one.getAllDevices+Rootobject'.-----   at 
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureArrayContrac (Type objectType, JsonContract contract) at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String reference)
```

My JSON response looks like this. I used JSON to c# converter tool online to get my getAllDevices class.

```
[ {
    "_id": "5cf528969bcb5a0069cb6039",
    "discovery": {
        "fake_discovery": false
    },
    "is_authorized": true,
    "name": "Plug In Module",
    "conditions": [],
    "actions": [
        {
            "_id": "5cf528969bcb5a0069cb603c",
            "last_executed": "2019-06-13T14:31:56.302Z",
            "action_def": {
                "hidden": false,
                "show_as_manual_action": true,
                "_id": "5a317841ac537b0013a2a7cc",
                "id": "turn_on",
                "name": "Turn On to {level}%",
                "order": 0,
                "requires_push_message": false,
                "simple_name": "Turn On to Brightness%"
            },

        {
            "_id": "5cf528969bcb5a0069cb603e",
            "last_executed": null,
            "action_def": {
                "hidden": false,
                "show_as_manual_action": true,
                "_id": "5a317899ac537b0013a2a7ce",
                "id": "set_brightness",
                "name": "Set Brightness to {level}%",
                "order": 3,
                "requires_push_message": false,
                "simple_name": "Set Brightness to Level%"
            },
            "params": [
                {
                    "ui": {
                        "interface": "slider",
                        "step_size": 5,
                        "step_hold_size": 10,
                        "presentation_value": 10
                    },
                    "values": [],
                    "id": "level",
                    "label": "Percent",
                    "type": "Number",
                    "default_value": 10,
                    "limit_lower": 0,
                    "limit_upper": 100
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "last_updated": "2019-06-13T14:32:05.413Z",
    "parent_ids": [
        "5cf03e05aa4d770038167dfd"
    ],
    "classification": "device",
    "states": []
}
]
```

Comment: Looks like you should be deserializing to `getAllDevices.Rootobject`, not `Class1`. It would help if you posted the JSON response as well, but I'm guessing you get an array of objects, not a single `Class1`...  You'll then need to modify your `for` loop to be `foreach (var item in obj.Property1) { ... }`

Comment: @RonBeyer I did give that a try and get the above exception.

Comment: Please provide an example of the JSON response you get.

Comment: @RossBush It really doesn't matter if they are using it in a single compiled assembly. Classes not marked `public` are automatically `internal`, which is public to the assembly. That isn't the problem here.

Comment: @V_stack Your JSON response string is incorrectly formed. Can you please post the correct JSON response string?

Comment: I added an image of the response.

Comment: @V_stack That is a long JSON string which is probably consists of array of values. If you can give us Minimal correct JSON string to parse out maybe first and second indicies of the JSON array. Or else you can use this tool to generate your model and then do the deserialization: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: You have serialized something and trying to deserialize it into something else, what you have serialized has attributes called: `discovery, name, is_authorized` I can not see them in your `Class1`, so add them to that class and try again.

Comment: @muaz Stackoverflow did not allow me to paste the entire content, so I just pasted the necessary information.

Comment: Make sure that the structure of your serialized `Class1` is the same of the structure  of the deserialized `Class1`, because obviously your deserilaized `Class1` misses those attributes I mentioned already.

Comment: Can any of you tell me how to access the above using JArray.parse?

Comment: @V_stack Are you able to parse your JSON string using this method? If you can, then refer to this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726197/parsing-a-json-array-using-json-net/15726500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use JArray.parse to fix this.

```
 parsedArray = JArray.Parse(receivedData);
 foreach (JObject ob in parsedArray.Children<JObject>())
                        {

                                var name = (string)ob["name"];

                                if (name == "My ecobee")
                                {
                                    device_id = (string)ob["_id"];

                                    var json = (JArray)ob["actions"];
                                    foreach (JObject ob1 in json.Children<JObject>())
                                    {
                                        var actionname = (string)ob1["action_def"]["id"];
                                        if (actionname == "increase_temp_by")
                                        {
                                            action_id = (string)ob1["_id"];
                                            strname = (string)ob1["params"][0]["id"];

                                        }
                                    }
                            }
```